# Get text before and after colon python

Tags: python

I have following example string:

```
'EXP DATE: 13.04.2022 PO: P101'
'LOCATION: 111 CONDITION: FN'
```

I need to split following strings to look like:

```
{"EXP DATE": "13.04.2022", "PO": "P101"}
{"LOCATION": "111", "CONDITION:" "FN"}
```

To achieve this i created following function:

```
def create_key_pair(lst):
    return {lst[i].replace(':', ''): lst[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)}
```

so if i pass

```
str_ = 'LOCATION: 111 CONDITION: FN'
create_key_pair(str_.split(" "))
```

i got

```
{"LOCATION": "111", "CONDITION:" "FN"}
```

but if i pass

```
str_ = 'XP DATE: 13.04.2022 PO: P101'
create_key_pair(str_.split(" "))
```

i got

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

since

```
EXP DATE
```

splited by space

Comment: Do the values ever contain spaces?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The problem is not well defined. If I say, for example, that I think the first result should be `{"EXP DATE": "13.04", ".2022 PO": "P101"}`, why is that wrong? Aside from that, please read [ask], and try to break the problem down into logical steps before asking. What things need to happen, step by step, in order to get the result? Then, what parts of this can't you do? Then, for the parts you can't do, do you see existing questions on Stack Overflow? Finally, if there is still something, choose one remaining, unanswered problem and ask **specifically**.

Comment: If the values potentially include spaces, how would you determine a multi-word key from a multi-word value? `"foo: bar bat hat: 10"` or can this never happen? is the value "bar bat" or is the next key "bat hat"?

Answer (score 1):

If the values (the part after the colon) cannot contain spaces, the following will work. The approach uses a regular expression to match any number of characters up to a colon followed by a space and then any number of non-space characters. Then split each match on the colon.

```
import re

def to_dict(s):
    matches = re.findall(r".+?: \S+", s)
    d = {}
    for m in matches:
        k, v = m.split(":")
        d[k.strip()] = v.strip()
    return d
```

If the values can contain spaces you'll have to find some other way of separating a value from the next key. JonSG gave the example in the comments of `"foo: bar bat hat: 10"`. With the above approach, you'll get `{"foo": "bar", "bat hat": "10"}`, but maybe you want `{"foo": "bar bat", "hat": "10"}`. From the information in the question the only pattern I can see is that the values do not contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

```
import re

def create_key_pair(s):
    data = {}
    for kv in re.findall('([^:]+:\s*[^\s]+)', s):
        k, v = re.split(':\s*', kv)
        data[k.strip()] = v.strip()
    return data
```

Usage:

```
str_ = 'LOCATION: 111 CONDITION: FN'
create_key_pair(str_)

# Output
{'LOCATION': '111', 'CONDITION': 'FN'}


str_ = 'EXP DATE: 13.04.2022 PO: P101'
create_key_pair(str_)

# Output
{'EXP DATE': '13.04.2022', 'PO': 'P101'}
```